# Gerrit: Inline code comments

Tags: gerrit

Does Gerrit support inline comments like the way [phabricator](https://secure.phabricator.com/D583#inline-835) does?

[image]

Can someone help me understand that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes of course, that is one of the key features of Gerrit.  Here is a random example I quickly found on the Android Gerrit instance: https://android-review.googlesource.com/#/c/31832/2/libc/bionic/libc_init_dynamic.c

Answer (score 0):

In gerrit page
Expand file, select code chunk to comment. The Tooltip "Press to comment" will appear.

[image]

Press this tool tip and type the comment.
To publish comments reply on this commit.

[image]